# Switch fasta seq depending on a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parsing, fasta

I have actually 2 fasta file named:

```
result1_aa.fasta
result2_aa.fasta
```

In these files I have my sequences such :

file `result1_aa.fasta`:

```
>gene1_B
ATTGGACCA
>gene2_A
ATTAGGAC
>gene90_B
ATTAGCCACA
>gene65_B
ATTGAG
```

file `result2_aa.fasta`:

```
>gene78_A
ATTGGACCA
>gene45_B
ATTAGGAC
>gene93_B
ATTAGCCACA
>gene54_A
ATTGACA
```

and I have a dataframe such :

```
geneA      geneB
gene78_A   gene1_B
gene2_A    gene45_B
gene90_A   gene93_B
gene54_A   gene65_B
```

they are actually in order (see the `_number`)
And what I would like is to get 2 new fasta file with the same order as the dataframe above, here it would be:

file `result1_aa_new.fasta:`

```
>gene78_A
ATTGGACCA
>gene2_A
ATTAGGAC
>gene90_A
ATTAGCCACA
>gene54_A
ATTGACA
```

file `result2_new_aa.fasta:`

```
>gene1_B
ATTGGACCA
>gene45_B
ATTAGGAC
>gene93_B
ATTAGCCACA
>gene65_B
ATTGAG
```

I tried some solutions but I cannot manage to keep the order in my fasta file as the dataframe...

With the Ami's solution:

```
    from Bio import SeqIO
    import sys
    from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
    import pandas as pd

    seq_0042_aa=open("seq_0042_aa.fasta","w")
    seq_0042_dna=open("seq_0042_dna.fasta","w")
    seq_0035_aa=open("seq_0035_aa.fasta","w")
    seq_0035_dna=open("seq_0035_dna.fasta","w")

    dN_dS_sorted=pd.read_table("dn_ds.out_sorted",sep='\t')

    seq1_id=dN_dS_sorted["seq1_id"] #first row
    seq2_id=dN_dS_sorted["seq2_id"] #second row


    from Bio import SeqIO
    results1 = list(SeqIO.parse("result1_aa.fasta", "fasta"))
    results1 = pd.DataFrame({'f_id': [r.id for r in results1], 'f_seq': results1})

    results1 = pd.merge(dN_dS_sorted, results1, left_on="seq1_id", right_on='f_id', how='left').dropna()
    results1 = list(results1.f_seq.values)

    with open("out.fasta", "w") as output_handle:
        SeqIO.write(results1, output_handle, "fasta")

    results2 = list(SeqIO.parse("result2_aa.fasta", "fasta"))
    results2 = pd.DataFrame({'f_id': [r.id for r in results2], 'f_seq': results2})

    results2 = pd.merge(dN_dS_sorted, results2, left_on="seq2_id", right_on='f_id', how='left').dropna()
    results2 = list(results2.f_seq.values)

    with open("out2.fasta", "w") as output_handle:
        SeqIO.write(results2, output_handle, "fasta")
```

here is the head of my dataframe:

```
seq1_id             seq2_id              dN               dS
g66097.t1_0035_0035 g13600.t1_0042_0042 0.10455938989199982 0.3122332927029104
g45594.t1_0035_0035 g1464.t1_0042_0042  0.5208761055250978  5.430485421797574
g50055.t1_0035_0035 g34744.t1_0042_0035 0.08040473491714645 0.4233916132491867
g34020.t1_0035_0035 g12096.t1_0042_0042 0.4385191689737516  26.834927363887587
g28436.t1_0035_0042 g35222.t1_0042_0035 0.055299811368483165    0.1181241496387666
```

Then, in the output I should get:

output1:

```
>g66097.t1_0035_0035
ATTGGAGATA
>g45594.t1_0035_0035    
TAGGAGGAGA
>g34020.t1_0035_0035
ATGGGAT
>g28436.t1_0035_0042
ATTGGAGA
```

and output2:

```
>g13600.t1_0042_0042    
ATGGGAGAGA
>g1464.t1_0042_0042 
ATGGAGGAGA
>g12096.t1_0042_0042    
ATGGAGGAA
>g35222.t1_0042_0035
ATGGAGAG
```

but I actually get: 
output1:

```
>g28436.t1_0035_0042
ATGAGAGAGA
>g1005.t1_0035_0035
ATAGGAGATA
>g28456.t1_0035_0035
ATGGAGATA
>g30148.t1_0035_0042
ATGGAGA
```

and output2:

```
>g35222.t1_0042_0035
ATAGGAGA
>g11524.t1_0042_0042
ATAGGAGA
>g31669.t1_0042_0035
ATGAGAGA
>g37790.t1_0042_0035
ATGAGGAGA
```

Here is the head of the fastafile1:

```
>g13600.t1_0042_0042
AGATAGAGA
>g1464.t1_0042_0042
AGATTAGA
>g34744.t1_0042_0035
ATAGAGGA
>g12096.t1_0042_0042
AGATATGA
```

here is the head of the fastafile2:

```
>g66097.t1_0035_0035
AGATTAGAGA
>g45594.t1_0035_0035
AGTATAGAGA
>g50055.t1_0035_0035
ATAGGAGAGA
>g34020.t1_0035_0035
ATAGGAGAG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do the first file. Again using [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO),

```
from Bio import SeqIO
results1 = list(SeqIO.parse("result1_aa.fasta", "fasta"))
results1 = pd.DataFrame({'f_id': [r.id for r in results1], 'f_seq': results1})
```

Now merge them:

```
results1 = pd.merge(df, results1, left_on='results_on', right_on='id', how='left').dropna()
```

(this assumes the column name is `results_on` - you didn't specify it.

Now get the sorted records:

```
results1 = list(results1.f_seq.values)
```

Write it out:

```
with open("out.fasta", "w") as output_handle:
    SeqIO.write(results1, output_handle, "fasta")
```

Comment: I updated my comment with your script and the result, maybe I wrote something wrong?

Comment: Looking at the output for your file 1, I guess that the entries before this one simply don't exist in the input file.

Comment: I posted the head of the fasta files, they however contain these gene

Comment: I finnally found a solution, thanks for your help :)